# Angular object will not map

Tags: angular

I have an list of objects coming over from a c# API the json structure of the object is:

```
{
"limitId": 1,
"limitText": "Testing 3",
"limitCreated": "2021-05-12T22:14:45.7133333",
"limitActive": true,
"personId": 1,
"limitType": {
    "limitTypeId": 3,
    "limitTypeText": "Open To Exploration",
    "limitTypeActive": true
  }
}
```

in my angular app I have the following model to accept that JSON payload:

**getLimits.ts**

```
export interface LimitType {
limitTypeId: number;
limitTypeText: string;
limitTypeActive: boolean;
}

export interface GetLimits {
limitId: number;
limitText: string;
limitCreated: Date;
limitActive: boolean;
personId: number;
limitType: LimitType;
}
```

To get this data I do the following:

**Limits.service.ts**

```
getLimits():Observable<GetLimits[]>{
console.log('In here');
var apiURL = this.api.getApiEndPointByName('GetLimits');
var returnable = this.http.get<GetLimits[]>(apiURL);
return returnable;
}
```

And in my component I attempt to map it directly to an array of GetLimits:

```
   public limits: GetLimits[] = [];
   getLimits() {
   this.limitsService.getLimits()
    .subscribe(limit => {
        this.limits = limit
        console.log(limit)
    });
}
```

Upon execution of this, this.limits returns an empty array.
I have no idea why!

Would love help from anyone that knows what I have done wrong :(

UPDATE

I am checking the results in a few ways,

In the GetLimits Components I do a console.log before I assign the observable to public limits.
This returns:

```
{
  "limitId": 1,
  "limitText": "Testing 3",
  "limitCreated": "2021-05-12T22:14:45.7133333",
  "limitActive": true,
  "personId": 1,
  "limitType": {
     "limitTypeId": 3,
     "limitTypeText": "Open To Exploration",
     "limitTypeActive": true
  }
}
```

I then, in the html do the following:

```
        <tr *ngFor="let row of limits">
                                  {{row}}
                                  <td>{{row.LimitId}}</td>
                                  <td>{{row.LimitText}}</td>

                                  <td class="td-actions text-left">
                                    <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-success" onclick="alert(row.LimitId)">
                                        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-link">
                                        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
```

Which the results are:

```
[object Object]
```

I also console log out the results of this.limits which returns:

```
[]
```

Comment: When is `getLimits()` called? How and when are you checking that `this.limits` is empty?

Comment: Are you the backend is not returning an empty array? What response do you see in the networking tab of the browser? Or did you test the backend already (eg. using Postman)?

Comment: @igor I will add how I am checking this to the question

Comment: if you `console.log(this.limits)` in `ngOnInit` it will be `[]`. That's the nature of observables. Also `{{row}}` _is_ `[object Object]`. If you want to view it clearer use `{{row | json}}`. In terms of how to render observables `{{row.LimitId}}` etc. should work.

Comment: @AndrewAllen {{row | json}} wow! Thanks so much this makes debugging so much easier. The issue was capitalised L in limit.

Comment: @Caz1224 no problem. I recommend using an async pipe removing the need to subscribe eg. `<li *ngFor="let employee of employees$ | async">{{employee.name}}</li>` where `this. employees$ = someObservablePossiblyCallingAnAPIViaService`

Comment: @AndrewAllen thanks man, if you wanna put a answer I will mark it for those sweet sweet points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question resolved in comments but I'll give the canonical way to to this here:

component.ts

```
   public limits$: Observable<GetLimits[]>;

   ngOnInit() {
       this.limits$ = this.limitsService.getLimits()
                          // .pipe(
                          //     tap(data=>console.log(data)),
                          //     map(data => transformData(data))
                          // )
                          //
                          //  you can debug via the rxjs pipable operator tap and map via...map
   }
```

component.html

```
    <tr *ngFor="let row of limits$ | async">
        {{ row | json}}
    </tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<td>{{row.LimitId}}</td>
 <td>{{row.LimitText}}</td>
```

Change `LimitId` to `limitId` and `LimitText` to `limitText`.